# How many Greek gods are there in Greek mythology?

Tags: greeks, myths

I was wondering how many Greek gods there were. I'm working on a Greek school protect and need the answer. Thanks!

Comment: You might be able to find some lists doing an internet search. Regardless, welcome to Philosophy!

Comment: You might find some good answers for this question on the Mythology and Folklore SE: https://mythology.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Keep in mind there can be forgotten gods about which no info remains. So, you can never know you have the exact answer.

Comment: -1: Off-topic. You should ask this on Mythology&Folklore

Comment: i downvoted even-though off-topic isn't a good reason for that. it's a bad question!

Answer (score 1):

The following site came from doing an internet search on "Greek gods list":   The [Greek gods](https://greekgodsandgoddesses.net/gods/) page claims to be "A Complete List of Greek Gods, Their Names & Their Realms of Influence".  I counted 62 on the list.

There is also a page on [goddesses](https://greekgodsandgoddesses.net/goddesses/).